# メモリ管理、スタックのmutabilityについて

Tags: メモリ管理, assembly, memory-leaks, スタック

スタック領域に積んだ値は、関数がネストしてもFrame Pointerから遡って参照することができると理解しているのですが、
その場合、より深い場所にある値の上書きはできないのでしょうか?

また、できないとすればそれはなぜなのでしょう。
セキュリティでしょうか?

ただし、代入する値のサイズがもとの値以下であり、Growableでないことを前提とします。

無駄に手書きですが、こういうイメージです

```
 ーーーーーーー
|            |
|    関数     |
|            |
| ローカル変数 <-|
 ----------- | |
|            | |  上書きしたい
| ネストした  ---
|   関数      |
|            |
 ーーーーーーー
```

Comment: 破壊的代入とはどういう動作・操作を意図しているのでしょうか？もうちょっと読者にわかりやすい説明ができると回答が付くかもしれません。

Comment: すこし修正しましたが、伝わるしょうか。。。

Comment: 8086系のCPUしか知りませんが、C/C++言語の場合、最適化されたコンパイル結果を見ると、スタック内の値が直接書き込まれるコードになる場合もあります。関数から戻る場合に大量のPOPを実行するより早いと判断されるのだと思います。これは破壊ではありませんが参考になりますでしょうか。

Comment: コンパイラの最適化オプションの事ですけど。伝わりますでしょうか。

Comment: あ、はい。例えば、'''int x = 3; x += 3; printf("%d", x);'''の'x'が6としてアセンブリになるということでしょうか? でしたら、質問とは違います。

Comment: 最適化のくだりは場面の説明に過ぎないので回答とは無関係です。ところで8086系のESPレジスタは当然値が変更できます。やってみましたでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問するに至った動機と合致する答えになるのかどうか微妙な気がしますが

```
void func1(int* p) {
    ++p[4];
}
void func2(void) {
    int array[10]={0};
    func1(array);
}
```

上記コードはたいていの CPU (x86 も含む) で下記のような動きをします
- `func2()` がスタック上に配列 `array` を作成します
- `func1()` は自分の使っているスタックより深い階層にある配列 `array` を上書きします
- この操作の際にスタックフレームポインタを参照する必要はありません

C++ ラムダ式で自動変数をキャプチャするとか、「関数内関数」ができる言語では、親関数の自動変数を子関数から読み取ったり書き換えたりできます（子関数から見ると、スタック的により深い階層の値にアクセスすることになります）。ラムダ式のキャプチャは結局は参照ですし、アセンブラレベルでの実装上はスタック上のアドレスを扱うだけのことです。

Comment: こちらのコードをLLVM irに変換して理解がすすみました。
スタック構造について調べるとpush,popのみで上書きでの更新はデータ構造の範囲外なので、確信がもてていませんでした。
アドレスがわかれば更新可能ということで理解しました。

Answer (score 0):

回答になるかわかりませんが、
　1.当該ローカル変数がPUSHされたものである
　2.かつ他の関連する全ての変数のレイアウトとコードが自明。
なら、当該ローカル変数のアドレスが特定できます(EBPとESPで特定可能)。
アドレスが特定できれば書き換え可能と言えます。

Comment: アドレスが特定できれば上書き可能ということで理解しました。